# Hackers replaced my WordPress homepage

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, hacked-site

I forgot to remove the default admin/admin account on my blog. Somebody got in and has replaced my homepage with some internet graffiti.

I've used `.htaccess` to replace the page with a 403 error, but no matter what I do, my WordPress homepage is this hacker thing.

How can I set up my server so that ONLY MYSELF can view it while I'm fixing this via `.htaccess`? What steps should I take to eradicate them from my server?

If I delete the ENTIRE website and change all the passwords, is he completely gone?

Comment: It depends very much on how much access the hacker got. If he only has access to the admin interface of wordpress, then you could simply put in a password using .htaccess. This way others can't see the page while you can, and AFIAk you can redirect failed authentication attempts to the 403 page. If he got access to a shell somehow, in other words he would have some way to remove or otherwise circumvent the .htaccess then really, you probably have to look at cleaning out the entire server (fresh install or revert to backups if you have them).

Comment: Question for [webmasters.se]?

Comment: And crickets chirp. *sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I setup my server so that ONLY
>   MYSELF can view it while I'm fixing
>   this via .htaccess?

Use [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) to block the site from everyone who doesn't have the login and password (i.e. anyone who is not you).

> What steps should I take to eradicate
>   them from my server? If I delete the
>   ENTIRE website and change all the
>   passwords, is he completely gone?

If you completely uninstall the software, delete everything associated with it (e.g. directories) and re-install it from scratch you should be fine.